# DocuSign api supported scopes

Tags: docusignapi

when I was trying to grant permission to an application from organization dashboard, it asks for permissions (space-delimited list of supported OAuth scopes) - I tried signature, extended and impersonate individually and it seems ok but what I need to do is to be able to download all documents from all envelopes of all users, what is the permissions/scopes should I use? I could not find out a list of all supported scopes/permissions. can someone point me the link or shed some light on this? thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

Inbar's answer provides the scopes for the OrgAdmin API.

For the **eSignature REST API**, the scopes are on the [consent page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent).

They are:

- `signature` — Allows your application to create and send envelopes, and obtain links for starting signing sessions.
- `extended` — Issues your application a refresh token that can be used any number of times. This scope may only be granted in the Authorization Code flow.
- `impersonation` — Allows your application to access a user’s account and act on their behalf even when that user is not present. This scope is only used by JWT authentication.

Note: To request multiple scopes, use a space as the separator. Encode the space character as %20 in URIs.

**Clickwrap management API**

See the [docs.](https://developers.docusign.com/click-api/guides/auth) Scopes:

- `click.manage`    Enables all clickwrap operations, including creating, sending, and updating clickwraps; getting a list of clickwraps, creating user agreements, getting a list of users, and retrieving responses
- `click.send`  Send a new clickwrap or check for a previously sent one; no other operations.
- `extended` — Issues your application a refresh token that can be used any number of times. This scope may only be granted in the Authorization Code flow.
- `impersonation` — Allows your application to access a user’s account and act on their behalf even when that user is not present. This scope is only used by JWT authentication.

Answer (score 0):

John, there are a few different scopes, you can find them here:

https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/guides/auth

Comment: These are the scopes for just the OrgAdmin API.